# How can I make users embed their own youtube videos?

Tags: java

I'm creating a website where users can upload videos. But instead of uploading them to me they'll upload them to YouTube and then embed them onto my website. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Allow them to paste a URL. from there, generate an embed link.

Comment: You mean that I would have to embed them myself? Because that wouldn't be possible. There will be a lot more videos than I can handle.

Comment: I imagine you could use some code to generate an embed link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really very simple.  Your instructions should let them know they have to place their video on YouTube before they build the page on your site.  Then all they have to do is click the SHARE button on that video on YouTube and then copy the resulting URL into an input field on your page.  You then take care of all the formatting for that link.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Really helped me out a lot Gleen :)